# System.Web.Optimization vs Microsoft.Web.Optimization

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Those namespaces are somehow related to each other, but I do not understand the difference and when I need the one or the other?!

Can anyone please explain that to me?

Comment: I believe those are just different versions of the beta.

Comment: Happily now it's shipped it turns out we can use Web Optimization with .NET 4.0! I wrote a short blog post demonstrating how to get up and running with MVC 3 and Web Optimization if that helps: http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.com/2012/10/using-web-optimization-with-mvc-3.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft.Web.Optimization namespace has been replaced with System.Web.Optimization in 1.0.0-beta version of the Microsoft.Web.Optimization package. The System.Web.Optimization namespace  is going to be included in System.Web.dll for .NET 4.5 Framework release (according to [preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation).